# Finding 200th element of a ordered list that is 2K elements, generated by a ordered character set, in a 4 character space width

Tags: permutations, combinations

Finding $200$-th element of a ordered list that is over $2K$ elements long, generated by a ordered character set, in a $4$ character space width.

I have a list that consists of the `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` characters, that is placed in a character space that is then permutated across a $4$ character wide space, (`aaaa`, `aaab`, `aaac` and so on), and written to a ordered list. I want to calculate the $200$-th element, or line, of the list, in such that I can say line/element number $200$ of the generated list will the string `$x$x$x$x`, but am unsure of how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have banged my head on enough walls over this. So, the question, to be more definitive, would be how do I find the $200$-th element of a list that is ($26^4$) elements long, without creating the list element by element on a computer, with a ordered character set consisting of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`?

Comment: There is no objective way to answer this, as there is nothing in a list of permutations that dictates the order in which they are listed.

Comment: The question suggests lexicographic ordering, though this could have been made more explicit.

Comment: I've removed the "big-list" tag on this post. The "big-list" tag is for posts whose expected answers form large lists. They usually ask for examples or counter examples or references. It's not actually for problems that involve lists with a large number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just base$~26$ representations of integers. So to find the 200-th element, which is at position $199$ counting from$~0$, write it in base$~26$ as $199=0\times26^3+0\times 26^2+7\times26^1+17\times26^0$, and from the coefficients $(0,0,7,17)$ deduce the letters $(a,a,h,r)$. The 200th word on your list is "aahr".

Comment: thank you that seems to be the solution.